# User Account Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i get his error when login to Xampp > User Accounts

```
Error
```

SQL query: Copy DocumentationEdit Edit

(SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Hos

```
#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria
```

Comment: The first duplicate shows how you might be able to fix it using phpmyadmin, the second using command line utilities.